# viewing assembly code for Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, gcc, assembly, compilation, objc-message-send

I'm reading over [this awesome article](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-tour-part-2-setting-the-stage/) on friday.com. bbum shows some objective-c code and the corresponding assembly. **How can I view objective-c assembly code?**

Assume I'm compiling from the OS X Terminal using `gcc`.

Comment: If you are willing to use xcode, it has a built feature to view the assembly of a file.

Comment: Much of the assembly in that article was copy/pasted directly from the source;  the messenger in Objective-C -- objc_msgSend() -- is written in assembly directly.  Speaking of, I need to update the article for the newer runtime that supports tagged pointers, imps-as-blocks, and has a faster caching mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never tried with objective-c (it works with C) but I guess you can use simply

```
gcc -S program.m
```

You can also use `-fverbose-asm` to make a more readable output

Answer (score 6):

Use [otool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) after compilation, or `gcc -S <input>.c -o <output>.S`, or just use XCode, it's pretty awesome... `/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild` from the directory containing your project, then:

[image]

Comment: Actually his words were "OS X Terminal" but who's being pedantic?

Comment: I updated my answer with instructions for running XCode from the command line! Bahahahah anyway I think everybody is happy here